# Cast dynamically an Object

Tags: java, casting

I wonder If It is possible to cast dynamically an object in Java.

For example, something like this:

```
return (object1.getClass().getSimpleName()) Object2;
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Why?

Comment: @M.leRutte  The context is more complex, I am working with dynamic proxies and casting dynamically an object is crucial for such a goal. Otherwise, I have to do it manually.

Comment: Without more context it is impossible to answer, but in general the answer of @mureinik below is how you can ask a class object to cast an object. But not from incompatible types.

Comment: what is the point doing it inside a return statement? It will be reduced to the return type of the method, so you could just put in a cast with the same type as the method return type, e.g. `return (Foo) Object2;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Class.cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-):

```
return object1.getClass().cast(Object2);
```